# Question about the placement of resistors on a Marx generator

Tags: resistors, circuit-design, high-voltage

I'm a little unclear about why Marx generators are generally setup with their resistors like this:
[image]
What is the benefit of placing resistors where they are instead of having resistors in series with the spark gaps?  Are two reasons so that if the gap spacing for each of the gaps after the first is equal, they won't all fire at the same time and so there won't be resonating effects?  Part of why I ask is that it seems easier to model resistors in series with gaps in LT Spice, like in the simple model below, it gives a damped oscillating voltage as an output, but if I swap the two resistors, it gives me more of a ramp response.
[image]

Comment: If you put resistors in series with the spark gaps, you dramatically reduce the output current the Marx can deliver, turn a boom into a squeak. That's if it fires at all, because as a Marx erects, the stray capacitances to ground demand a charging current through the gaps, which fires all the remaining gaps rapidly. If the charge had to build up slowly through resistors, half the gaps would fire and their caps would start running down before the others fired, a very ragged performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resistors are also for spacing the various stages.  When you trigger the spark, much more current runs through the spark gaps than through the resistors, making them all in series.  Before that, with the spark gaps not conducting, the resistors conduct so the caps can be slowly charged in parallel.  It's like a voltage multiplier, but without all those clumsy and easily-destroyed semiconductors.